# How to compile and run JCUDA in netbeans?

Tags: java, cuda, jcuda

I want to compile and run my jcuda codes in an IDE (Netbeans) on ubuntu 16.04. I've already installed Netbeans, Maven, java and cuda 8.0.

For example, I want to run sample of vector add that the java file is [JCudaVectorAdd.java](http://www.jcuda.org/samples/JCudaVectorAdd.java) and the cuda kernel is [JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu](http://www.jcuda.org/samples/JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu). How can I compile and run this simple example using Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a maven project and add dependencies to the pom.xml file of the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcuda</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcublas</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcufft</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcusparse</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcusolver</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcurand</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnvgraph</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jcuda</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcudnn</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then add the `JCudaVectorAdd.java` to the project and give the address of `JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu` file in the java file:

```
String ptxFileName = preparePtxFile("JCudaVectorAddKernel.cu");
```

now you can build your project successfully.